# Sending Rich Text Format email using Outlook 2003

Tags: python, email, outlook

I am trying to send a Rich Text Format email message using Outlook 2003.
The following code results the RTF HTML source code to be dumped into the mail message body.

What should I do in order to fix that, and make Outlook display the formatted data and not the source HTML ?

```
import win32com.client

RTFTEMPLATE = """<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV=3D"Content-Type" CONTENT=3D"text/html; =
charset=3Dus-ascii">
<META NAME=3D"Generator" CONTENT=3D"MS Exchange Server version =
08.00.0681.000">
<TITLE>%s</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- Converted from text/rtf format -->

<P DIR=3DLTR><SPAN LANG=3D"en-us"><FONT =
FACE=3D"Calibri">%s</FONT></SPAN><SPAN =
LANG=3D"en-us"></SPAN></P>

</BODY>
</HTML>"""

Format = { 'UNSPECIFIED' : 0, 'PLAIN' : 1, 'HTML' : 2, 'RTF'  : 3}
profile = "Outlook"
subject="Subject"
body = "Test Message"

session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
session.Logon(profile)
mainMsg = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mainMsg.To = "test@test.test"
mainMsg.Subject = subject
mainMsg.BodyFormat = Format['RTF']
mainMsg.Body = RTFTEMPLATE % (subject,body)
mainMsg.Send()
```

EDIT: When using HTMLBody instead of Body, Outlook detects the message as HTML and not as RTF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use RTF, you will need to convert your HTML to RTF format. Check out the [zopyx package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zopyx.convert/1.1.9).

To use HTML, change the line:

```
mainMsg.Body = RTFTEMPLATE % (subject,body)
```

to:

```
mainMsg.HTMLBody = RTFTEMPLATE % (subject,body)
```

Comment: When using HTMLBody instead of Body, Outlook detects the message as HTML and not as RTF.